# Защита своего приложения

Tags: java, android, google-play, защита, реклама

Здравствуйте.Имеется приложение с встроенными покупками, рекламой.С помощью Lucky Patcher его можно подправить.Например удалить или отключить рекламные активити и пользоваться приложением.Отключил активити через Lucky Patcher, в своем приложении проверяю на доступность этой активити

```
PackageInfo pis = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo (getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
pis.activities[3].isEnabled();
```

Получается активити всегда включена.Может кто знает как это дело проверить, и как можно защитить свое приложение от подобных программ?

Comment: Хороший же вопрос, зачем удалять? Что ответов нет — так бывает, иногда ответы приходят позже.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, конечно от Lucky Patcher  я не сделал, а от freedom простенькую сделал.

Comment: @Ivan а у вас root  на мобиле стоит?

Comment: @Lex Hobbit нет и не собираюсь

Comment: @Ivan тогда укажите ссылку на Lucky Patcher, который использовали. При беглом просмотре кишков, я заметил, что он подменяет `hosts` файл и извесные имена направляет на локалхост, где уже сам слушает запросы...

Comment: @Ivan я к тому, что нужно понять механизмы какие используются в Lucky Patcher, и соответственно думать как их обойти.

Comment: Так как я понял идет редактирование кода

Comment: Это будет перетягивание каната. Патч под ваше приложение будут обновлять, сводя вашу защиту на нет, если будет спрос. Так что оцените, сколько вы теряете, отказываясь от защиты. Не так уж много, на деле. Устройств с рутом процентно не так уж много, с рутом и патчером и того меньше.

Comment: Нативный вариант?

Comment: С нативным вариантом не дружу.

Comment: Значит и не будет безопасности.

Answer (score 4):

Самый лучший способ: перестать страдать фигней и делать качественное приложение. Чтобы при попытке пропатчить его, пользователя останавливала не защита, а его совесть, его уважение к вам, его желание вас отблагодарить. И если он все равно решил вылечить приложение от жадности, то никакой защитой его не вернуть, автор приложения просто сделает хуже себе же.

Мой ответ на подобный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283143/. И если пользователь захочет вылечить приложение от жадности, он это всегда сделает. Если не Фридомом или Лаки Патчером, то АПКТулом и ручной правкой.

Самое лучшее, что вы можете сделать - это поставить себя на место человека с ЛакиПатчером и подумать, что можно сделать с приложением дальше, с позиции именно пользователя, который является самым главным человеком в деле разработки приложений.

Answer (score 1):

не знаю,может бредовая идея.. Но что если проверять при каждом запуске вашего приложения установлен ли Lucky Patcher или нет? если установлен то приложение будет показывать что-то типа "удалите Lucky Patcher и переустановите приложение". Переустановить ибо юзер может скачать отключить рекламу и удалить, либо копай в сторону сертификатов.

Comment: Я сделал немного по другому.Lucky Patcher же может имя своего пакета менять все не перечислишь.Не понял насчет сертификатов.

Answer (score 0):

Я защищал свое приложение и от Freedom, и от Lucky Patcher. Сначала проверял установленные пакеты на устройстве пользователя. В итоге перешел на использование Proguard совместо с [Android Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html), после этого мое приложение не поддавалось на взлом с помощью Lucky Patcher. [Тут](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/index.html) можешь изучить, как встроить в приложение эту библиотеку. Вот можешь скачать [мое приложение](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jqsoft.games.kids.alphabet) и попробовать на нем LuckyPatcher.